# GAE http request to GCE via Serverless VPC Connector

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Google App Engine app (python 2.7 - it's an old project in the middle of upgrading!) that needs to make queries to an Elastisearch instance on Google Compute Engine. I'm able to make the requests using the GCE public ip address without an issue, but I'd prefer not to expose the GCE instance to the public internet.

- The app engine app is in region us-central
- The compute engine instance is in region us-central1, zone us-central1-f
- The compute engine instance is in vpc network "default". (not a legacy network)
- I've set up a Serverless VPC connector in us-central1, on default network.
- I've set up the app engine app.yaml to use the connector.

But http requests to the compute engine private IP address (10.128.0.2) get connection failures, <strike>and DNS lookups on the internal DNS name for the compute engine fail</strike> edit: dns lookup does work using `socket.gethostbyname`.

```
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to connect to server at URL: http://10.128.0.2:9200/indexname
```

The same request succeeds when using the public IP address (when I open the VPC firewall on port 9200).

#### Snippet from the app engine app config:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: '1'
env: standard
threadsafe: false
instance_class: F4

network:
  name: default
vpc_access_connector:
  name: >-
    projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/connectors/connector0301
```

#### gcloud beta --account="myaccount" --project="myproject" app describe:

```
authDomain: gmail.com
codeBucket: staging.myproject.appspot.com
databaseType: CLOUD_DATASTORE_COMPATIBILITY
defaultBucket: myproject.appspot.com
defaultHostname: myproject.appspot.com
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
  useContainerOptimizedOs: true
gcrDomain: us.gcr.io
id: myproject
locationId: us-central
name: apps/myproject
servingStatus: SERVING
```

#### gcloud beta --account="myaccount" --project="myproject" compute instances describe (just the network snippet):

```
networkInterfaces:
- accessConfigs:
  - kind: compute#accessConfig
    name: External NAT
    natIP: SNIPPED
    networkTier: PREMIUM
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
  fingerprint: M087cXbOWII=
  kind: compute#networkInterface
  name: nic0
  network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/myproject/global/networks/default
  networkIP: 10.128.0.2
  subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/myproject/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default
```

#### gcloud beta --account="myaccount" --project="myproject" compute networks vpc-access

```
connectors list --region=us-central1
CONNECTOR_ID   REGION       NETWORK  IP_CIDR_RANGE  MIN_THROUGHPUT  MAX_THROUGHPUT  STATE
connector0301  us-central1  default  10.8.0.0/28    200             300             READY
```

#### gcloud beta --account="myaccount" --project="myproject" compute networks vpc-access connectors describe connector0301 --region=us-central1

```
ipCidrRange: 10.8.0.0/28
maxThroughput: 300
minThroughput: 200
name: projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/connectors/connector0301
network: default
state: READY
```

#### gcloud --account="myaccount" --project="myproject"  compute firewall-rules describe default-allow-internal

```
allowed:
- IPProtocol: tcp
  ports:
  - 0-65535
- IPProtocol: udp
  ports:
  - 0-65535
- IPProtocol: icmp
creationTimestamp: '2020-02-11T11:18:09.906-08:00'
description: Allow internal traffic on the default network
direction: INGRESS
disabled: false
id: '1434668200291681054'
kind: compute#firewall
logConfig:
  enable: true
name: default-allow-internal
network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/default
priority: 65534
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/firewalls/default-allow-internal
sourceRanges:
- 10.128.0.0/9
- 10.8.0.0/28
```

Do serverless VPC connectors not work for internal IP http requests?

Comment: Update: DNS resolution does work after all, so I have a feeling the VPC connector doesn't help with internal IPs for http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do serverless VPC connectors not work for internal IP http requests?

Serverless VPC connectors work for internal IP http requests using `urllib.request` in the python37 runtime, but not using `urllib2` or `urlfetch` from `google.appengine.api` in the python27 runtime. (Reminder that [urllib2 uses urlfetch under the hood on app engine python27](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests))

Since this is part of an older project that is slowly moving from python27 to python37, for now I put the internal ip http requests into a separate service so they could use the new runtime.

Comment: Hi! I have a similar problem as yours. I am trying to make a private connection from Cloud Function to an App Engine endpoint. I have attached the Serverless VPC Connector to the function and force App Engine to listen to internal traffic only, but the request are not reaching the App Engine. My project is Python 3, and I am sending the request from Cloud Function using the `requests` module. I have also tried to `urllib.request`, but it did not work either. Do you know how to fix this? Is the `google.appengine.api.urlfetch` available for Python 3 so that I can use it from my Cloud Function?

Comment: I am trying the same, cloud function to app engine. How are you getting the internal IP address for app engine?

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob I was making a socket connection to a compute engine instance, and I used socket.gethostbyname since I know the host names for the compute engine instances within the VPC.

I haven't used a VPC to connect to app engine from cloud functions, but I believe that is within the supported services?

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access#supported_services

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc

Comment: @Kelly thanks for the links, but here my problem is that all the articles mention to use internal IP address once the VPC connector is in place. I am not able to find the private IPs for app engine.